# What is the programmatic approach to not give focus to the Froala editor.$el (textarea) when clicking a toolbar button on the editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

At the moment I'm struggling to understand, which way is best to not give focus to the `Froala` editor when clicking on a toolbar button?

I tried to access the editor by events but i cant get this to work and I am not sure this is the right option

```
    new FroalaEditor(".froala_editor", {    
      events: {
        'toolbar.focusEditor': function () {
          alert("hello")
          console.log(this);
        }
      }
    });
```

We have `editor.button.bindCommands()` but I do not understand this either.

What I could get to work was

```
    var editor = new FroalaEditor(".froala_editor", {}, function () {
      $("button#moreText-1").click(function() {
          editor.$el.blur()
      });
    });
```

Now when I click the *moreText* button it seems that now there is no focus on the editor and the caret does not show.

But is there a more *api* type way to do this. And for instance there must be a event fired to focus the *textarea* on click, so what is the best way to ensure the *textarea* isn't getting focus then being blurred.

Comment: can you provide more details, so do you have a button that you want to focus on the editor when you click it?

Comment: Well no. I want to 'NOT' focus the textarea as froala does when you click any of the toolbar buttons and the caret appears and on mobile forces the keypad to open. I would not like to do that on the `more` buttons that drop extra options as it seems unintuitive to the user. But i am starting to see that if the textarea becomes unfocused and we have typed something froala has a hard time finding the last position again. IDK it seems to be quite here and there when its used with a touch screen..

Answer (score 2):

Triggered after the Froala Rich Text Editor gets focused.

```
new FroalaEditor('.selector', {
  events: {
    'focus': function () {
      // Do something here.
      // this is the editor instance.
      console.log(this);
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: I will let you know I did try this and I could not get it to0 work. Now I try it and yeah, I, I get a output in console log. I think the problem is with this is that this is fired when the element is focused. I would like it before that.

Comment: Hi. Ill be honest with you here. I don't, think, there is a way to do this in froala. Even my first example is getting focused and then blurred the same as your example. I tried multiple things, like `events { commands.mousedown (btn) }` and `editor.events.disableBlur();` method. It seems like froala wants to keep this by design as the focus keeps the caret in the correct position. All, I could do was change my design so on mobile the editor only has 3 `more` buttons that way the editor is small and doesn't jump too far off screen when the keyboard opens. I upvoted you but